# How can I check the XML Parser components version bundled within the Oracle Database?

Tags: xml, oracle

I was wondering if it is possible to extract from an Oracle's system view the version of the many XML tools bundled within the Oracle database Server.

Is that possible? What view contains this info?

Comment: I'm referring to the XML parser is behind the SQL XML features, such as XPATH or XSLT and such

Comment: I saw this MOS article that looks pertinent to your question, How to Identify the Version of XML Parser for Java Installed Inside the Database (Doc ID 177411.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Follow MOS [Doc ID 177411.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/SearchDocDisplay?_adf.ctrl-state=qr27g77jz_9&_afrLoop=563246287153033) Regarding Calling the `getReleaseVersion()` Accessor**

Create a Java function that calls and returns the accessors value, `getReleaseVersion()`, from `oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser`.

The Java doc for the 12.1c database is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAXML/oracle/xml/parser/v2/XMLParser.html#getReleaseVersion__).

The MOS document provides an example.

---

**Addendum regarding `C` and `C++` XML apis and their versions**

The 12.1c Oracle database does have an XML apis for `C` and `C++`.

The [XML Developer's Kit Programmer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDK/adx_c_gs.htm#ADXDK1300) documents set-ups for `C` and `C++`.

If you navigate to the databases `$ORACLE_HOME\lib`, you can identify the versions of these apis.

To search the `C` version, you would issue the unix piped command:

`strings libxml11.a | grep -i developers`

To search the `C++` version, you would issue this unix piped command:

`strings libxml11.a | grep -i developers`

<sub>* Assumes the Oracle database is installed on an Unix/Linux operating system.  Also, these search commands are identified in the kit identified above</sub>

Comment: That's a good resource! Just a further question... do you think the Java parser is the only XML component ? May there be even additional C/C++ based components?

Comment: I added additional information about C/C++ based components